# Support size classes for many device and orientations?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, autolayout, orientation

I'am doing app that needs to support iPhone 4s, 5, 6, 6+ in portrait and landscape mode. At the moment I use w Any - h Compact for size classes but in portrait doesn't look ok. Does anyone knows which option cover both orientations for all iPhone devices

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general you should make all of your design in wAny/hAny. This is for all devices and all orientations.

If you want to make another design for a special device at a special orientation then use that specific size class only for that special design.

Comment: can you please add any link which develops complex UI's in storyboard while supporting all mentioned devices.Thanks